# is there a mistake in React documentation about How to think in React?

Tags: reactjs, components, state, documentation

I'm learning React so I preferred to start with the documentation. In the last chapter about "Thinking in React" (https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) they recommend asking some questions in order to identify when a piece of data is or not part of the state:

> Let’s go through each one and figure out which one is state. Ask three
>   questions about each piece of data:
>
> Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t
>   state.

and then:

> The search text and the checkbox seem to be state since they change
>   over time and can’t be computed from anything.

I agree with that but at the same time both elements are passed as props to SearchBar component. So here they wouldn't be fulfill that question.

Comment: `props` in one component may be `state` in another. It depends on the context of the question.

Comment: You just typically want to avoid creating state in a child component that mirrors the props passed in. Its a fairly common bad practice, so they're encouraging you to use props as props. But passing state to a child component as props is not bad, and is essential to most react apps.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; It's not a mistake in the docs.

To further explain, lets say we have two components `Parent` and `Child`.

This would be a bad usage of state in the `Child` component:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       foo: 'bar'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Child foo={this.state.foo} />
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       foo: props.foo // this is unncessesary, we've just duplicated props
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.foo}</div>
  }
}
```

Based on the questions presented, we don't need `foo` in the state of `Child`. Instead we should reference it through `props`:

```js
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.foo}</div>
  }
```

But that doesn't mean `foo` can't be in the state of `Parent` (as long as it satisfies the questions in its own context). Since currently it doesn't, lets say `Parent` changes `foo` on a button click:

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       foo: 'bar'
    }
  }

  render() {
    return 
      <div>
         <Child foo={this.state.foo} />
         <button onClick={() => this.setState({ foo: 'You clicked me!' })}>Click Me</button>
      </div>
  }
}
```

Now `foo` in `Parent` does satisfy the questions listed to qualify as state because it changes over time. However, it does not qualify as state in the context of `Child` because `Child` does not change the value, it just displays it.

It doesn't always stay this simple. That's why the questions are the way they are. It doesn't say "Never create state based on props". Sometimes that's exactly what you want to do.

Lets look at an example:
Lets say `Child` has a text input and we want `Parent` to tell it what the default text should be.

```js
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Child default_text="This is what you wanted to type right?" />
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       text: props.default_text // Now it serves a purpose!
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        value={this.state.text} 
        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ text: e.target.value })} 
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Now we've reversed the situation. `props` is used to initialize `state` in `Child`, but it makes sense this time because the value is going to change over time. Whereas, it no longer makes sense to have `state` in `Parent` because its just a default value and won't be changing.

Hopefully that makes a little more sense.